# Android TableLayout - Application has stopped

Tags: android

When running the application we have received an error message "unfortunately the app has stopped." When debugging we got an error that the source was not found.

We notice that adding the tableLayout caused the problem:

```
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background1"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <TableLayout
      android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

      <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:padding="@string/padding" >

          <TextView

              android:id="@+id/textView1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
              android:text="Cell Id"
              android:textSize="@string/textsize"
              android:textStyle="@string/textstyle" />

      </TableRow>

      <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="@string/padding" >

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView2"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Cell Location" 
              android:textSize="@string/textsize"
              android:textStyle="@string/textstyle"/>
      </TableRow>

      <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:padding="@string/padding" >

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView3"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="LAC" 
              android:textSize="@string/textsize"
              android:textStyle="@string/textstyle"/>
      </TableRow>

      <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:padding="@string/padding" >

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView4"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Signal Strength"
              android:textSize="@string/textsize"
              android:textStyle="@string/textstyle" />
      </TableRow>

      <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:padding="@string/padding" >

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView5"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Rx Quality"
              android:textSize="@string/textsize"
              android:textStyle="@string/textstyle"/>
      </TableRow>

      <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:padding="@string/padding" >

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView6"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="neighbor cells"
              android:textSize="@string/textsize"
              android:textStyle="@string/textstyle" />
      </TableRow>

      <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:padding="@string/padding" >

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView7"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="send"
              android:textSize="@string/textsize"
              android:textStyle="@string/textstyle" />
      </TableRow>

      <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:padding="@string/padding" >

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView8"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Scrambling code"
              android:textSize="@string/textsize"
              android:textStyle="@string/textstyle" />
      </TableRow>

      <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:padding="@string/padding" >

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView9"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="N Cells" 
              android:textSize="@string/textsize"
              android:textStyle="@string/textstyle"/>
      </TableRow>

     <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:paddingTop="30dp"
          android:paddingLeft="105dp"
           >
      <Button
          android:id="@+id/button1"

          android:onClick="press"

          android:text="PRESS" />
 </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
package com.manish.tabdemo;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.NeighboringCellInfo;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.SignalStrength;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.telephony.gsm.GsmCellLocation;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
    TextView text,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6, text7, text8,text9;
    TelephonyManager Tel ;
    GsmCellLocation cellLocation; 
    SignalStrength signalStrength;
    MyPhoneStateListener    MyListener;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        MyListener   = new MyPhoneStateListener();
        Tel       = ( TelephonyManager )getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        Tel.listen(MyListener ,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
        text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        text3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        text4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        text5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        text6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        text7 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        text8 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        text9 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_tab_host, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /* Get the Signal strength parameters */
    String RxLev, RxQual; 
    private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
    {
      @Override
      public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
      {
        super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
        RxLev = "RxLev = " + String.valueOf(signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength()) + " dbM";
        RxQual = "RxQual = " +String.valueOf(signalStrength.getGsmBitErrorRate());
      }

    };


    //Reading longitude and latitude
    private static final String TAG = null; 
    String s;
    //String longitude;
    //String latitude;
    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            text6.setText("");
           // pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           Toast.makeText(
                 getBaseContext(),
                    "Location changed: Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + " Lng: "
                        + loc.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           String longitude = "Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude();
            Log.v(TAG, longitude);
            String latitude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();
            Log.v(TAG, latitude);

            String s = longitude + "\n" + latitude ;
            text6.setText(s);

        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    }


    int cid;
    int lac ;

    public void press(View v)
    {
        try
        {

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        GsmCellLocation cellLocation= (GsmCellLocation)telephonyManager.getCellLocation();
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);
        int psc = 0;//cellLocation.getPsc();
        Log.d(TAG, "PSC = " + psc);
        //Neighboring Cell  
        List<NeighboringCellInfo>  neighCell = null; 
        TelephonyManager telManager = ( TelephonyManager )getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
        neighCell = telManager.getNeighboringCellInfo();  
        String cells=""+neighCell.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < neighCell.size(); i++) 
        {  
            try {  
                  NeighboringCellInfo thisCell = neighCell.get(i);  
                  int thisNeighCID = thisCell.getCid();  
                  int thisNeighRSSI = thisCell.getRssi();  
                  cells = "1 "+thisNeighCID+" - "+thisNeighRSSI+"\n";  
                } 
            catch (NumberFormatException e) 
            {  
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  NeighboringCellInfo thisCell = neighCell.get(i);  
                  cells += neighCell.toString();  
            }  
       }  
         cid = cellLocation.getCid();
         text.setText("Cell id= " + String.valueOf(cid));
         text2.setText("Cell Location= "+cellLocation.toString());
         lac = cellLocation.getLac();
         text3.setText("Location Area Code= " + String.valueOf(lac));
         // view Rx Level
         text4.setText(RxLev);
         text5.setText(RxQual);
         // view longitude and latitude 
         //text5.setText(latitude);
        text7.setText("Scrambling code = " + psc);
        text8.setText("Neighboring Cells = " + cells);
         //text5.setText("Latitude= " + String.valueOf(lat));
        // text6.setText("Longitude= " + String.valueOf(lng));


        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            text5.setText(e.toString());

        }
    }


    HttpClient httpClient; 
    HttpPost httppost;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs; 
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpEntity entity;

    public void sendd(View v)
    {
        text4.setText("sendd");
          try 
          { 
             httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/syriatel/add.php");
             int uid = 0; 
             InputStream is = null;
             StringBuilder sb = null;
             String result; 
             nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id","3" ));
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cell_name","ttty5y  "+cid));
             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


             response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
             is=entity.getContent();
             BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),8);
             sb = new StringBuilder(); 
             sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
             String line = "0"; 
             while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
             { 
                 sb.append(line + "\n");
             }
             is.close();
             result = sb.toString();
            text9.setText(result);

         }
         catch (Exception e) 
         {
             text5.setText( e.toString());
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), 1000);
             Log.e("errorin connection",e.toString()); 
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), 1000);} 

        }
}
```

LogCat:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.manish.tabdemo/com.manish.tabdemo.TabHostActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.manish.tabdemo/com.manish.tabdemo.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.widget.TableRow
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.manish.tabdemo/com.manish.tabdemo.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.widget.TableRow
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2135)
    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:766)
    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:430)
    at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:257)
    at com.manish.tabdemo.TabHostActivity.onCreate(TabHostActivity.java:26)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
    ... 11 more
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.widget.TableRow
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
    at com.manish.tabdemo.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:47)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
    ... 21 more
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
    ... 35 more
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x3
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:464)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3572)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:475)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
    at android.widget.T
    08-06 12:16:57.635: I/Process(29348): Sending signal. PID: 29348 SIG: 9
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.manish.tabdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.manish.tabdemo.TabHostActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.manish.tabdemo.HomeActivity"/>
             <activity android:name="com.manish.tabdemo.AboutActivity"/>
                  <activity android:name="com.manish.tabdemo.ContactActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Could you share the error that you came across?  It might help us pinpoint the issue.  CommonsWare posted comment should direct you.

Comment: share the stack trace

Comment: I just run your code it works no crash. The output was"Cell ID", "Cell Location", etc.? Just clean project and try again. IS these  <activity android:name="com.manish.tabdemo.AboutActivity"/>
                  <activity android:name="com.manish.tabdemo.ContactActivity"/> two activity available in your package?

Comment: Yes they are available.. What do you think the problem??
It doesn't work with me

Answer (score 0):

Your `TableRow  android:id="@+id/tableRow2"` are all the same `tableRow2`.

Please try to change it.

Hope it may help you.

Comment: I posted it in an answer.. please see it and help me

Comment: Hava you definition your `TabHostActivity` in AndroidManifest？

Comment: It is defined by default.. I didn't edit anything in Manifest.
You can see it in the question

Comment: Please add `<activity ndroid:name="com.manish.tabdemo.TabHostActivity" />` under `</activity>`.

Comment: Maybe I have to see all project to identify the problem.

Comment: May I send you the project to your email?